# How do I make my gem place a .dll in a folder in the system PATH upon installation?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

... and remove it upon un-installation, of course.

The issue is that other programs being called from my gem need to be able to find a certain file in the system PATH - setting the PATH programatically doesn't work, as these programs are being called in a way that they get a fresh environment.

I tried including these .dll files as "executables" in the gemspec, but that only seems to get some symlink type files in the `{ruby}/bin` folder, which causes errors because the programs in question are expecting the actual .dll.

As it is, I just have a note in the README asking people to manually copy the .dll files to a folder in the PATH, but it seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: What OS are you targeting?  dlls are windows but symlinks are not!?!?  Is your code on guthub perchance?  Or could you post your gemspec?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have mentioned this is on Windows.  The gemspec is similar to the one here: https://github.com/matadon/mizuno/blob/master/mizuno.gemspec

Comment: OK so what do you mean by "that only seems to get some symlink type files in the {ruby}/bin" ?  There's no such thing as a symlink in Windows.

Comment: Whenever a gem is installed, a ruby script pointing to the actual gem binary is created in the {ruby}/bin folder... guess I should have said "symlink-like".

Comment: Are you using or Hoe or Jeweler or anything like that?  Or straight gem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the dll is a native lib required by a java class?

If so, you can just put it somewhere in the lib folder and call java.lang.System.load to load it before the java class is used. It doesn't have to be in system PATH this way.